# existence and unicity solution of boundary second order problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

let the second order boundary problem 
$$e^{-2x}y''- (e^{-2x}+ 4 e^{-x}) y'+ 3y = e^{2e^{x}}, x \in ]0,1[$$
with a good choice of boundary conditions

How we can prouve that this second order boundary problem admits a unique solution?

Answer (score 1):

According to the above suggestion (@ Robert Israel) we have $\frac{dy}{dx}=e^x\frac{dy}{dt}$ and $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=e^x\frac{dy}{dt}+e^{2x}\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}$. Substituting these into the equation we get the following transformed the equation with constant coefficients:
$$y''-4y'+3y=e^{2t}$$ with the general solution $$y(t)= c_1e^{t}+c_2e^{3t}-e^{2t}$$ for $t\in(1, e)$, where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are arbitrary constants. To ensure a unique solution  you have determine these constants uniquely. This can be accomplished by an appropriately chosen boundary conditions. For example, if you let $y(a)=\alpha$ and $y(b)=\beta$ for some given numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta$, then there will be a uniqu solution for any $a,b\in(1, e)$ with $a\ne b$. For general form of boundary conditions you can look at the Sturm-Liouville problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the change of variables $t = e^x$ may help.

Comment: but what's the theorem we can use to prouve the existence and unicity of this boudary values second order problem?

Comment: Once you change variables you can explicitly solve the differential equation and find all solutions of the boundary value problem.